# Сохранение формы js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как можно сохранить использую только нативный js данные введенные в форму что бы потом их можно все вывести ?

Пример:

1 пользователь ввел: Андрей 16 Минск

2 пользователь ввел: Анна 22 Москва

Нужно что бы эти данные сохранились и вывелись на другой странице средствами только js

Comment: гляньте на LocalStorage и IndexedDB.

Comment: сохранить куда?

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin local.storage

Comment: и в чем проблема?

Comment: Как в  LocalStorage ? На другом клиенте будет свой независимый LocalStorage. Разве не так.

Answer (score 1):

JS работает на стороне клиента (браузера). Данные сохраненные только на стороне JS-а (LocalStorage, куки и т.п.) будут доступны только для текущего пользователя. Если Вам необходимо что бы данные, вводимые разными пользователями, были видны и первому и второму пользователю, используйте базу данных (MySQL и т.п.), но для работы с этим всем придется использовать серверные языки (PHP и т.п.).

Comment: JS тоже на сервере может быть (NodeJS).

Comment: Да, но не в его случае)

Comment: Не опровергнуто - значит возможно.

Comment: дык, по условию, вроде "только нативный js", не?